# Wrap iframe tags with div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML which contains a post content:

```
<div class="post-content">
  <iframe width="40" other-properties>
     iframe code
  </iframe>
  Other content and other tags
</div>
```

How can I wrap all iframe tags found in post-content with a div:

```
<div class="post-content">
  <div class="video">
    <iframe width="40" other-properties>
       iframe code
    </iframe>
    Other content and other tags
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $("iframe").wrap("<div class='video'></div>");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".post-content iframe").wrap('<div class="video"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this in browser, you can use jQuery (see docs – http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/):

```
$(".post-content").wrapInner("<div class='video'></div>")
```